# Hide borders on extra-small devices with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hide, border

I have this code:

```
 <div class="container my-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="c-sin"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></h1>"TEXT"</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="c-cen"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></h1>"TEXT"</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div class="c-des"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></spa n></h1>"TEXT"</div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The problem it's the borders on a PC are visible like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/MuU0sya.png]

but on a xsmall device are visible like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/JZ8pGlL.png]

So I've decided to hide them on xsmall device, but I don't know how to do it.
Here are also the CSS I've used to create the borders:

```
.c-sin {
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.c-cen {
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I created a new classes using SASS:

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-down($breakpoint) {
    .border-#{$breakpoint}-left-none {
        border-left:none !important;
    }
    .border-#{$breakpoint}-right-none {
        border-right:none !important;
    }
    .border-#{$breakpoint}-top-none {
        border-top:none !important;
    }
    .border-#{$breakpoint}-bottom-none {
        border-bottom:none !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can set a class like "border-xs-right" to your div and the right border will disappear for extra-small screens.  "border-sm-right" would make the right border disappear for small and xs screens.

Of course, you would have to use SASS to do this.  If that's not something you want to do, the compiled code looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .border-xs-left-none {
    border-left: none !important; }
  .border-xs-right-none {
    border-right: none !important; }
  .border-xs-top-none {
    border-top: none !important; }
  .border-xs-bottom-none {
    border-bottom: none !important; } }

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .border-sm-left-none {
    border-left: none !important; }
  .border-sm-right-none {
    border-right: none !important; }
  .border-sm-top-none {
    border-top: none !important; }
  .border-sm-bottom-none {
    border-bottom: none !important; } }

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .border-md-left-none {
    border-left: none !important; }
  .border-md-right-none {
    border-right: none !important; }
  .border-md-top-none {
    border-top: none !important; }
  .border-md-bottom-none {
    border-bottom: none !important; } }

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .border-lg-left-none {
    border-left: none !important; }
  .border-lg-right-none {
    border-right: none !important; }
  .border-lg-top-none {
    border-top: none !important; }
  .border-lg-bottom-none {
    border-bottom: none !important; } }

.border-xl-left-none {
  border-left: none !important; }

.border-xl-right-none {
  border-right: none !important; }

.border-xl-top-none {
  border-top: none !important; }

.border-xl-bottom-none {
  border-bottom: none !important; }
```

Comment: This answer genuinely should be accepted as valid answer.

Comment: that is not how Bootstrap works.`border-xs-right` for example, following BS syntax, should display a border from XS and up. `border-sm-right`would do the same for SM and up. Not the other way around. Also your CSS/SCSS actually states a `border-xs-right-none`, which kind of makes this answer invalid in itself.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution on my own:

```
@media(max-width:767px){

.c-sin {
width: 100%;
border: hidden;
padding-left: 10%;
 }

.c-des {
width: 100%;
border: hidden;
padding-right: 10%;
 }

.c-cen {
width: 100%;
border: hidden;
padding-left: 10%;
padding-right: 10%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap not natively supporting breakpoints operators you may let it display forever but apply a `overflow-hidden` in the parent container to hide the border. Here is a pure bootstrap 4 example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group text-center overflow-hidden w-100">
      <div class="row d-flex mt-30">
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-right border-right mb-30 mb-sm-0">
              <div class="col-12 text-center p-20 bg-info">
                  <p class="align-middle" style="height: 120px;">
                      some contents here
                  </p>
                  <label for="">left label</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-left">
              <div class="col-12 text-center p-20 bg-secondary">
                  <p class="align-middle" style="height: 120px;">
                      some contents here too
                  </p>
                  <label for="">right label</label>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```